# .htaccess http to https AND mvc query string

Tags: apache, .htaccess, http, redirect, https

So, the problem is, that in my VirtualHosts I`ve redirect to https, which follows as:

```
...
Redirect permanent / https://www.example.com/
...
```

And then in .htaccess I`ve

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?_url=/$1 [QSA,L]
```

But when typing http://example.com, in url appears https://www.example.com/**?_url=/**

Why there appears "?_url=/" when it shouldn`t.
Apache version: 2.4.7

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Comment out this line from Apache config:

```
Redirect permanent / https://www.example.com/
```

Then use this code in root .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [NE,R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?_url=/$1 [QSA,L]
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it works perfectly, but, still - I really would like to know, why it was not working correctly, when redirecting in VirtualHost config, and why apache suggests avoiding redirecting in .htaccess http://httpd.apache.org/docs/trunk/rewrite/avoid.html

Comment: Mixing `Redirect` directive with other `mod_rewrite` can create problems because they are invoked at different time by Apache.